# How to solve this error 'Warning: Use of undefined constant asDollars - assumed 'asDollars' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) '

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project to build a website. What should I do to remove this error?

This is newer version of PHP.

```
if(!function_exists(asDollars)){
    function asDollars($value){
        return '$' .number_format((double)$value,8);
    }
}

$pricetotal = asDollars("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
// Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
$x = $i + 1;
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . 
$x . '" value="' . $product_name . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . 
    $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
```

Error message:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant asDollars - assumed 'asDollars' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyOnlineStore\cart.php on line 124

Comment: Function prototype `function asDollars($value)` Note ONE PARAMETER!  Calling the function `asDollars("%10.2n", $pricetotal);` Note TWO PARAMETERS.

Comment: You are right sir. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the string:

```
if (!function_exists('asDollars')) {
```

However, the function you're defining in this case doesn't seem to match the way you're calling it later. You call it with two arguments, a format string and a value, but your definition only takes a value.

It's not clear why you think you need to define the function here conditionally. Is there some reason you can't ensure that the library that defines `asDollars` is properly loaded?

Comment: Thanks sir it worked.  Arguments were the problem and single quotes too. I have now fixed this problem.